# MMdev doesn't display ad in my WP7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads

I try to add a Millennial ad in my application. I followed every step their wiki gives but it doesn't work on my WP7 emulator.

I'd like to know whether the mmdev ad works only with the real WP7 device? I think I filled in everything in the webpage of mmdev in order to register my app.

Is there someone who already face this problem?

Comment: You should contact their support, rather than ask here.

Answer (score 1):

I tried their SDK, even though they say you should wait 1 to 2 hours to activate the APPID of your app, I remember I waited for a day.